# Create a binary heatmap based on variables relationship

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have the dataframe below

```
DrugName <- c("as","df","fg","gh","jk")
value <- c("AD","AD","AD","AD","SEL")
MELT <- data.frame(DrugName, value)
```

and I want to create a heatmap that will have drug names as rows , and target symbols as columns (below the heatmap) and a grid square should be white if there is no association between a drug & a target
or black if there is an association between a drug & a target.
 I use:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(MELT, aes(value, DrugName)) +
 geom_tile() +
 geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white") + 
 scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black"))
```

and I get:
[image]

I do not understand why the plot seems to have 3 column while the values are 2 and also why the coloring seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `table` to count each combination of 'DrugName' and 'value', convert to `data.frame`. Map `fill` to a discrete version of 'Freq'.

In the example, the counts are only 0 or 1, and you can map fill color with `fill = factor(Freq)`. If 'Freq' also has values `> 1`, then you may coerce to a binary version of 'Freq': `fill = Freq != 0`.

```
ggplot(data.frame(table(MELT)), aes(value, DrugName, fill = factor(Freq))) +
  geom_tile(color = "grey") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: I have a question. I tried to run this in a case in which I have more than 2 types of values and I get Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 2 provided. But I do not want a third color in my heatmap

Comment: The number of different 'value' is not a problem. Perhaps you mean that you have  more than two different 'Freq'? If so, make 'Freq' a binary variable, e.g. `fill = Freq != 0`. Remember to provide toy data  of sufficient complexity. Cheers.